# Filling List from model in view

Tags: asp.net-core

I have problem with filling model in View. At start GET methot pass model formContainsField with filled list(fields) and i have to edit this list(fields) in form .In POST method after fill form, "fields" is empty.

Class FormContainsField:

```
 public class FormContainsField
{
    public int? IdForm { get; set; }
    public List<IdFieldBool> fields = new List<IdFieldBool>();
}
```

Class IdFieldBool

```
public class IdFieldBool
{
    public int IdField { get; set; }
    public string NameField { get; set; }
    public bool? ContainsField { get; set; }
}
```

And my form:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
    <p>
        <label asp-for="IdForm">Name and surname:</label>
        <input asp-for="IdForm" />
    </p>
    @for(int i=0;i<Model.fields.Count();i++)
    {
        <p>
            <input asp-for="fields[i].NameField" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Whether the form should contain a field?</label>
            <select asp-for="fields[i].ContainsField">
                <option value="">Wybierz opcję</option>
                <option value="true">Yes</option>
                <option value="false">No</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    }
    <button type="submit">Zapisz</button>
</form>
```

I think that `<input asp-for="fields[i].NameField" />` and `<select asp-for="fields[i].ContainsField">` are problems, but i dont know how resolve this. I want to fill this list(fields) in View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten `{get;set;}` for `fields`,change your `FormContainsField` model to

```
public class FormContainsField
{
    public int? IdForm { get; set; }
    public List<IdFieldBool> fields { get; set; } = new List<IdFieldBool>();
}
```